# Ubuntu - Installation Problem

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I have tried to install Ubuntu.

Everything seemed to work fine until "Looking for other operations systems" showed up in the installer. Then, this error message appeared:

> ubuntu ubiquity: find: '/toget/boot/efi/... Input/output error
>
> ubuntu kernel: FAT - fs (sda2): error invalid access to fat (entry
>   0x...)
>
> ubuntu kernel: FAT - fs (sda2): error invalid access to fat (entry
>   0x...)

and then the same loop.

I have an HP laptop with WINDOWS 10 and have disabled both the fast boot option and the secure boot one.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm not 100% certain, but I THINK FAT is not a reliable format to boot Ubuntu installation on. I used http://www.pendrivelinux.com/ which I used the second time I attempted to boot my installation because if I remember correct, I tried using a different program and it put my usb format into FAT and it simply did not work. Again, not 100% certain, but worth a try to use a different format.

Comment: I used Rufus and I followed the instructions.
https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows